# plot heading direction with folium onto an object

Tags: python, leaflet, plotly, data-visualization, folium

I have plotted a heatmap with the following data.

[image]

I have thousands of rows. Its just a sample. I also wanted to see the google map view of that coordinate. So I did something like this.

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap
from folium.plugins import FastMarkerCluster


default_location=[11.1657, 45.4515]
m = folium.Map(location=default_location, zoom_start=13)


heat_data = [[row['lat'],row['lon']] for index, row in test.iterrows()]

# Plot it on the map
HeatMap(heat_data).add_to(m)

callback = ('function (row) {' 
                'var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(row[0], row[1]), {color: "red"});'
                'var icon = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({'
                "icon: 'info-sign',"
                "iconColor: 'white',"
                "markerColor: 'green',"
                "prefix: 'glyphicon',"
                "extraClasses: 'fa-rotate-0'"
                    '});'
                'marker.setIcon(icon);'
                "var popup = L.popup({maxWidth: '300'});"
                "const display_text = {text1: row[0], text2: row[1]};"
                "var mytext = $(`<div id='mytext' class='display_text' style='width: 100.0%; height: 100.0%;'>\
                <a href=https://https://www.google.com/maps?ll=${display_text.text1},${display_text.text2} target='_blank'>Open Google Maps</a></div>`)[0];"
                "popup.setContent(mytext);"
                "marker.bindPopup(popup);"
                'return marker};')
            
m.add_child(FastMarkerCluster(heat_data, callback=callback))


# Display the map
m
```

Now for every gps coordinate I want to plot ***a small arrow*** or ***few small arrows*** in the angle of **heading_direction** and if possible show the **distance_of_item** in that angle from the gps coordinate. The expected outcome may be something like this.

[image]

In the above image, the location pointer is the gps coordinate, the direction and angle would be according to heading direction angle and there is a little star plotted which is the object. The object should be placed at a distance(in meters) mentioned in the dataset. I am not sure how to achieve that. Any lead or suggestions are most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Deb, do you mind to elaborate the expected output?

Comment: Hi @rpanai, I have edited the question and added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- given your sample data is an image, have used alternate GPS data (UK hospitals) then added distance and direction columns as random values
- given requirement is to plot a marker at location defined by distance and direction, first step is to calculate GPS co-ordinates of this.

  1. use UTM CRS so that distance is meaningful
  2. use high school maths to calculate **x** and **y** in UTM CRS
  3. convert CRS back to WSG 84 so that have GPS co-ordinates
- you have tagged question as **plotly** so I have used **mapbox** line and scatter traces to demonstrate building a tiled map
- sample data is 1200+ hospitals, performance is decent
- **geopandas** data frame could also be used to build **folium** tiles / markers.  Key step is calculating the GPS co-ordinates

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shapely
import math
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import io, requests
# get some public addressess - hospitals.  data that has GPS lat / lon
dfhos = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("http://media.nhschoices.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text),
    sep="¬",engine="python",).loc[:, ["OrganisationName", "Latitude", "Longitude"]]

# debug with fewer records
# df = dfhos.loc[0:500]
df = dfhos

# to use CRS transformations use geopandas, initial data is WSG 84, transform to UTM geometry
# directions and distances are random
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data=df.assign(
        heading_direction=lambda d: np.random.randint(0, 360, len(d)),
        distance_of_item=lambda d: np.random.randint(10 ** 3, 10 ** 4, len(d)),
    ),
    geometry=df.loc[:, ["Longitude", "Latitude"]].apply(
        lambda r: shapely.geometry.Point(r["Longitude"], r["Latitude"]), axis=1
    ),
    crs="EPSG:4326",
).pipe(lambda d: d.to_crs(d.estimate_utm_crs()))

# standard high school geometry...
def new_point(point, d, alpha):
    alpha = math.radians(alpha)
    return shapely.geometry.Point(
        point.x + (d * math.cos(alpha)),
        point.y + (d * math.sin(alpha)),
    )

# calculate points based on direction and distance in UTM CRS.  Then convert back to WSG 84 CRS
gdf["geometry2"] = gpd.GeoSeries(
    gdf.apply(
        lambda r: new_point(
            r["geometry"], r["distance_of_item"], r["heading_direction"]
        ),
        axis=1,
    ),
    crs=gdf.geometry.crs,
).to_crs("EPSG:4326")
gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326")


# plot lines to show start point and direct.  plot markers of destinations for text of distance, etc
fig = px.line_mapbox(
    lon=np.stack(
        [gdf.geometry.x.values, gdf.geometry2.x.values, np.full(len(gdf), np.nan)],
        axis=1,
    ).reshape([1, len(gdf) * 3])[0],
    lat=np.stack(
        [gdf.geometry.y.values, gdf.geometry2.y.values, np.full(len(gdf), np.nan)],
        axis=1,
    ).reshape([1, len(gdf) * 3])[0],
).add_traces(
    px.scatter_mapbox(
        gdf,
        lat=gdf.geometry2.y,
        lon=gdf.geometry2.x,
        hover_data=["distance_of_item", "OrganisationName"],
    ).data
)
# c = gdf.loc[]
fig.update_layout(mapbox={"style": "open-street-map", "zoom": 8, 'center': {'lat': 52.2316838387109, 'lon': -1.4577750831062155}}, margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"r":0})
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, looks good. I was thinking of using haversine distance formula to get the coordinate of the points. Also, could you suggest why I am getting attribute error for gdf.estimate_utm_crs() -> 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'estimate_utm_crs'.
I tried with the latest geopandas version 0.10.0. Still getting the error.

Comment: I was using geopandas 0.9.0, have just upgraded to 0.10.0 and still works...minimal code `gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=pd.DataFrame({"name":["test"]}), geometry=[shapely.geometry.Point(0.406042, 51.379997)], crs="EPSG:4326").estimate_utm_crs()` does it work?

Comment: Nope, still getting AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'estimate_utm_crs'. I am not sure what is the issue here

Comment: `import pyproj
import geopandas as gpd

print(gpd.__version__, pyproj.__version__)` what does this return? for me **0.10.0 3.2.1**. I suspect you are running in a *venv* where geopandas is not version you think...

Comment: Ahh, you are correct, in the env in which i was running had 0.6.1 version of geopandas. Thanks a lot!!